# Performance issues after upgrade to Adobe Commerce 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, database, performance, mariadb, magento2.4.6

My Adobe Commerce was running fine, but after the upgrade, I can see via New Relic that it takes more time to process queries.

I tried to upgrade my MariaDB to versions 10.4 and 10.6.

Is there any additional config needed when upgrading to Adobe Commerce 2.4.6?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue listed above?

Comment: Yes, I posted the answer here, I had to setup extra configs on MariaDB @WilsonHauck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are some specific configuration parameters. It will be mainly visible during the reindex benchmark.

Run these parameters in your MariaDB to optimize it:

```
SET --optimizer-switch='rowid_filter=off';
SET --optimizer-use-condition-selectivity=1;
SET --query-cache-type=ON;
```

[Adobe Commerce Configuration Best Practices.](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/performance-best-practices/configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution ...
Ensure that your Magento database is running on a supported version of MariaDB. According to the [Adobe Commerce 2.4.6 release notes](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/adobe-commerce/2-4-6.html), MariaDB 10.4 and 10.5 are supported. Make sure you have the necessary MariaDB version installed on your server and that Adobe Commerce is configured to use it.

Check the MariaDB configuration parameters to ensure that they are optimized for Adobe Commerce. Some of the important parameters that you may need to adjust include `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `innodb_log_file_size`, and `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`. Adobe Commerce recommends setting these parameters based on the available memory and disk space on your server.

Consider enabling query caching in MariaDB. This can help reduce the query processing time by storing the results of frequently executed queries in memory.

Monitor the server resource usage using tools like `top`, `htop`, or `sar` to identify any bottlenecks that may be affecting the application performance.

Make sure that you have applied all the latest Adobe Commerce patches and updates, as these may contain performance improvements and bug fixes.

It is always recommended to perform well...

Answer (score 0):

we have noticed a huge degradation on PHP-FPM CPU usage with Adobe Commerce 2.4.6, not related to database.
We are still investigating but have you noticed same issue on your side?

Comment: yes @jonathan-ribas

Answer (score 0):

For Improve your site performance and speed. Apply below points

- Merge Javascript and CSS Files and remove unnecessary CSS and js
  files
- Uninstall Irrelevant Extensions
- Enable Caching
- Choose a Fast
- Web Hosting Set up a Content Delivery Network (CDN)
- Optimize Images  on Your Magento Store
- Update to the Latest Magento Version
- Use Lightweight Magento Themes
- Clean Database Logs
- Update Indexers Enable
- Flat Categories and Products

Happy Coding...